# Reverse Words Codewars

Tags: java, string

I need to reverse words in a string. I tried in this manner:

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String str : splitWords) {
       if (str.length() < 5) {
           builder.append(str);
       else
           builder.append(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());

       builder.append(" ");
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();
}
```

It is failing for the test case `"   "` where it should return `"   "` (same string). Instead, my code returns `""`.

Comment: also for "                      " mulitple spaces

Comment: `return builder.toString().trim();`?

Comment: What's the purpose of Python tag in this question?

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem statement is.  Are you supposed to retain all spaces and punctuation in the String?  Are you supposed to reverse the words in a sentence, reverse the letters in words, or both?